# authorized_key permission check

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

I came across something I have never seen. Please remeber this is a new server. Normally when logging in with public/private key, I need to have the ~/.ssh/authorized as 0600 and i normal set the folder ~/.ssh/ to 0700 with out these ssh wont normally let me login. For what ever reason This time when I logged into this new server that i just setup and put a key but forgot to change permissions it still let me login. What flag should I be looking for in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StrictModes` option controls whether permission and ownership checks are performed.

Comment: and this should be set to "yes" to make sure permissions are checked?

Comment: That is correct.